# Getting BadImageFormatException from other exception's StackTrace

Tags: c#, x86, stack-trace, badimageformatexception

In my server I'm getting an exception which I catch and it seems to be ok.

The problem is that when I'm writing its **StackTrace** I'm getting **BadImageFormatException**.

I've tried to debug the server. Stopped on a breakpoint when catching the exception, I can see all its fields, but in the StackTrace I see the BadImageFormatException.

*Any ideas what causes to this problem?*

**My server details -**

It is written in C# with .NET FW 4.
I also use FrameWork which is written in Managed C++.
I compile my server to x86 platform. And run the server on x64 machine.

**The full BadImageFormatException -**

System.BadImageFormatException: The parameters and the signature of the method don't match.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo.GetParameters(IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, MemberInfo member, Signature sig, ParameterInfo& returnParameter, Boolean fetchReturnParameter)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Exception.GetStackTrace(Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Exception.ToString(Boolean needFileLineInfo)
   at System.Exception.ToString()
   at log4net.ObjectRenderer.DefaultRenderer.RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, Object obj, TextWriter writer)
   at log4net.ObjectRenderer.RendererMap.FindAndRender(Object obj, TextWriter writer)

Comment: [`BadImageFormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) only has a few possible causes. Most likely, you're trying to use two components/assemblies with incompatible versions of the .NET Framework or that have been compiled for different platforms (32-bit vs 64-bit). To actually answer the question, we'll need more information relevant to the above. For example, I see from the stack trace that you're using log4net. What platform is that compiled for, versus your application? Is there a separately compiled library that accompanies your app, etc.

Comment: Not log4net casues it. In debug mode I also can't see the StackTrace of the problematic exception.

Comment: Something is wrong with the metadata in one of the assemblies.  Short from file damage, this has to be caused by the way they were built.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use Spring.NET? Recently I had the same problem when implementing IErrorHandler in WCF to log exceptions  and in my case problem was in Spring.NET. I've updated Spting.NET to version 1.3.1 and now it works fine.

from changelog
[SPRNET-1284] - IL code generation can result in System.BadImageFormatException in Windows 2008

Answer (score 1):

This happens if your executing process is running as x86 (if set to anycpu and running on a win32bit machine) but somewhere down the road it tries to load an assembly that has explicitely compiled as x64.. or vice versa. x64(or anycpu on x64 machine) tries to load an explicit x86 compiled assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Some obfuscators can cause this exception when they inject invalid metadata.